# Get the value of the child nodes in a xml with unknown depth

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I get an XML like this:

```
<menu>
  <is>
    <not>
      <l>Title</l>
      <s>url1</s>
      <t>1</t>
      <is>
        <hlua>
          <l>Title</l>
          <s>url2</s>
          <t>0</t>
            <is>
              <frme>
                <l>Title</l>
                <s>url3</s>
                <t>1</t>
              </frme>
            </is>
        </hlua>
        <chrj>
          <l>Title</l>
          <s>url4</s>
          <t>1</t>
            <is>
              <cgas>
                <l>Title</l>
                <s>url5</s>
                <t>1</t>
                <is>
                  <el12>
                    <l>Title</l>
                    <s>url6</s>
                    <t>1</t>
                  </el12>
                </is>
              </cgas>
              <cael>
                <l>Title</l>
                <s>url7</s>
                <t>0</t>
              </cael>
            </is>
        </chrj>
      </is>
    </not>
  </is>
<menu>
```

I don't know the name of the child nodes, only the name of node "menu".
I wold like to get a list of values nodes: "s" if their node "t" = 1 and if his parent node "t" = 1

I would like to get this list:

- url1
- url4
- url5
- url6

In the XML example
I don't get the url "url2" because his node "t" = 0
I don't get the url "url3" because although his node "t" = 1, his parent node "hlua" has his node "t" = 0

How can I do this with LINQ?

Thanks!

I think this solves my question:

```
List<XElement> listurls = (from elements in xe.Descendants()
    //Elemento
    let t_element = elements.Element("t")
    let t_element_value = t_element != null ? t_element.Value : String.Empty

    //Elemento Padre
    let parent_element = elements.Parent.Parent
    let t_element_parent = parent_element.Element("t")
    let t_element_parent_value = t_element_parent != null ? t_element_parent.Value : "1"

    where t_element_value.EndsWith("1") && t_element_parent_value.EndsWith("1") && elements.Element("u").Value!="#" && elements.Element("u").Value != "" 
    select elements.Element("u")).ToList();
```

Comment: is that still a question or have you found your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why in the expected result you expect to see url1 - there is no ancestor element that has a child t element whose value equals "1". Anyways I come up with the following query you may want to take a look at:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(
@"<menu>
  <is>
    <not>
      <l>Title</l>
      <s>url1</s>
      <t>1</t>
      <is>
        <hlua>
          <l>Title</l>
          <s>url2</s>
          <t>0</t>
            <is>
              <frme>
                <l>Title</l>
                <s>url3</s>
                <t>1</t>
              </frme>
            </is>
        </hlua>
        <chrj>
          <l>Title</l>
          <s>url4</s>
          <t>1</t>
            <is>
              <cgas>
                <l>Title</l>
                <s>url5</s>
                <t>1</t>
                <is>
                  <el12>
                    <l>Title</l>
                    <s>url6</s>
                    <t>1</t>
                  </el12>
                </is>
              </cgas>
              <cael>
                <l>Title</l>
                <s>url7</s>
                <t>0</t>
              </cael>
            </is>
        </chrj>
      </is>
    </not>
  </is>
</menu>");

var urls = from url in xDoc.Descendants("s")
            let ancestorWithTChildElement = url.Parent.Ancestors().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Elements("t").Any())
            where (string)url.Parent.Element("t") == "1"
            && ancestorWithTChildElement != null && (string)ancestorWithTChildElement.Element("t") == "1"
            select url;

foreach (var urlElement in urls)
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)urlElement);
}
```

It results in:

```
url4
url5
url6
Press any key to continue . . .
```

(url1 is missing as there is no ancestor element who has a t child element at all

Answer (score 0):

I get it!!!
Solution:

```
List<string> listurls = (from a in xe.Descendants("s")
   let ancestros = a.Ancestors().Elements("t").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value.EndsWith("0"))
   where ancestros == null
   select a.Value).ToList();
```

=D

Comment: If this is the answer then you should consider marking it as accepted so that other SO users can find it easier. Looking at your question history you haven't marked any answers as accepted, it would be worth reviewing the latest answers to see if any of them answer your question yet and marking them as accepted.